# How to fix broken Windows update as files in Windows/Installer are removed?

Tags: windows, windows-update, uninstall, windows-server-2008-r2, installer

I made a mistake that removed files in C:\Windows\Installer and maybe some other hidden folders, in order to save disk space in C drive. But this action screwed Windows update, now the .net framework and some other SP updates are unable to either upgrade or un-install, due to unexpected errors of missing files...

Is there any chance that I can recover my system? To reinstall the whole OS is too costly...

Thanks

To add more info, I'm using windows server 2008 r2, installed .net framework, silverlight, visual studio and sql server 2008 r2.
The broken updates are several for .net framework, one for silverlight, one for visual studio, two SP for SQL server, one for office file validation.

Comment: It costs nothing to reinstall Windows.  Please explain why that isn't an option.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, it is an option... but I don't think it costs nothing, if I reinstall OS and every programs I now installed, and get them all updated, it will take me many hours...

Answer (score 0):

I have solved broken .net framework updates by removing all version of it via a tool called '.NET FRAMEWORK CLEANUP TOOL', and solved more by install visual studio 2012.

I solved silverlight one via this link: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/error-c080fcdb9a28ldade0silverlightmsi-cannot-be/ac98ce14-a7c2-4f63-868b-c2f9145d0aaf

The other two main, vs2010sp1, sql server sp, are still left broken.